# How to configure the ingress routing in istio for sub pages?

Tags: istio

I have a Loadbalancer service to a webapp.

The page should be launched as http:///productpage
if we open http://LB , it will show only empty page as the main product is in productpage url.

So, how to configure this in istio gateway VirtualService?
Please suggest.

The samples I tried.

deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mart-service
  labels:
    app: mart
    service: mart
spec:
  selector:
    app: mart
  ports:
    - name: http 
      port: 80
      targetPort: 18170

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: mart-details
  labels:
    account: mart
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mart-deployment
  labels:
    app: mart
    version: v1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mart
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mart
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: mart-details
      containers:
        - name: mart
          image: martserver.azurecr.io/mart:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 18170
              name: mart-port
          #securityContext:
              #runAsUser: 1000
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /home/spring/AppData/Local/erwin/Mart Server/
              name: mart-volume
      volumes:
      - name: mart-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: martpv


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
 name: martpv
 labels:
   app: mart
   version: v1
spec:
 accessModes:
 - ReadWriteMany
 storageClassName: azurefile
 resources:
   requests:
     storage: 5Gi
```

gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: martserver-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

virtualservice:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: martserver
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - martserver-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /MartServer
    - uri:
        exact: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: mart-service
        port:
          number: 80
```

Please ignore the image now as it is private repo.
And the product is working correctly as I tried with LoadBalancer type service and connecting.

The page is not opening: http://IG/MartServer

And, the kiali output.

[image]

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. Also, please show us what you already tried, you should include [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added the code I tried, please check it

Comment: I would strongly recommend going carefully through official Istio documentation. [Traffic Management](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/), [Ingress Gateways](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/), [Request Routing
](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/). Most of the issues you face can be solved by careful reading of docs.